# Is IQmining worth the investment?

Tags: altcoin, mining-profitability, cryptography

I am interested in investing in crypto-contracts, is IQmining worth the investment?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any mining operation short of buying hardware (ASICs, GPUs) is a scam.

IQ Mining appears to be a ponzi scheme of some form based on a quick Google.